# Two timers causing conflict in WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I have two timers (`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`) in a WinForms application.

Both timers start at the same time.  One timer starts and stops throughout the life of the program updating three labels, the other just runs and does its work at every tick event updating one label.  However, when the first timer is running code in its tick event the second timer isn't running.

In the first timer tick event code I have inserted multiple `System.Threading.Thread.Yield();` statements, but the second timer is still being blocked.  Searches for this comes up null.

I tried using system threading for the second timer, but it isn't doing anything.

I'm at a loss.
Any ideas?

```
public partial class fMain2 : Form
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer2;
    private Thread tThread;
    
    private int totTime;
    private int curTime;
    private int exTime = 0;
    public int runTime = 0;
    
    private void cmdRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //calculate total time
        totTime = iCount * iDuration;
        lblTotTime.Text = totTime.ToString();
        lblTotEx.Text = exTime.ToString();
        System.Threading.Thread.Yield();

        curTime = int.Parse("0" + txtDuration.Text);
        
        System.Threading.Thread.Yield();

        this.Refresh();

        strFile = "Begin" + ".wav";
        snd.SoundLocation = strSoundFilePath + strFile;
        snd.PlaySync();
        
        //select first item in the listview
        lvTimer.Items[0].Selected = true;
        lvi = lvTimer.Items[0];
        lvTimer.Refresh();
        
        strFile = lvi.SubItems[1].Text + ".wav";
        snd.SoundLocation = strSoundFilePath + strFile;
        snd.PlaySync();
        System.Threading.Thread.Yield();

        strFile = "Go" + ".wav";
        snd.SoundLocation = strSoundFilePath + strFile;
        snd.PlaySync();
        
        //attempted using a thread for timer2
        timer.Start();
        //tThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(timer2.Start));

        timer2.Start();
        //tThread.Start();
    }
        
    private void timerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strFile;
        
        curTime -= 1;
        totTime -= 1;
        
        exTime += 1;

        System.Threading.Thread.Yield();

        lblCurTime.Text = curTime.ToString();
        lblTotTime.Text = totTime.ToString();
        lblTotEx.Text = exTime.ToString();
        this.Refresh();
        
        System.Threading.Thread.Yield();

        if (curTime == 0)
        {
            timer.Stop();

            System.Threading.Thread.Yield();
            System.Threading.Thread.Yield();

            strFile = "Stop" + ".wav";
            snd.SoundLocation = strSoundFilePath + strFile;
            snd.PlaySync();

            System.Threading.Thread.Yield();
            System.Threading.Thread.Yield();
            
            if (totTime == 0)
            {
                //this marks the end of the program
                timer2.Stop();
                //tThread.Abort();
                
                //more code but not relevant
                return;
            }
            else
            { //we are still working down the listview
                
                try
                {
                    lvi = lvTimer.Items[lvi.Index + 1];
                    lvTimer.Items[lvi.Index].Selected = true;
                    lvTimer.FocusedItem = lvTimer.Items[lvi.Index];
                    lvTimer.Refresh();
                    System.Threading.Thread.Yield();
                    System.Threading.Thread.Yield();
                    System.Threading.Thread.Yield();
                }
                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException ei)
                {
                    strFile = "End" + ".wav";
                    snd.SoundLocation = strSoundFilePath + strFile;
                    snd.PlaySync();
                    bRunning = false;
                    ResetTime();
                    return;
                }

                curTime = int.Parse("0" + txtDuration.Text);

                lblCurTime.Text = curTime.ToString();
                lblTotTime.Text = totTime.ToString();

                System.Threading.Thread.Yield();
                System.Threading.Thread.Yield();
                
                //I'm wondering if the soundplayer is causing the problem
                strFile = lvi.SubItems[1].Text + ".wav";
                snd.SoundLocation = strSoundFilePath + strFile;
                System.Threading.Thread.Yield();
                System.Threading.Thread.Yield();

                snd.PlaySync();

                System.Threading.Thread.Yield();
                System.Threading.Thread.Yield();
                
                strFile = "Go" + ".wav";
                snd.SoundLocation = strSoundFilePath + strFile;
                snd.PlaySync();
                
                System.Threading.Thread.Yield();
                System.Threading.Thread.Yield();
                
                System.Threading.Thread.Yield();
                
                timer.Start();
            }
        }
    }
    
    private void timer2Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //this is all timer2 does.  It runs as long as the 
        //  program is running.
        runTime += 1;
        lblTotTotal.Text = (runTime / 60).ToString()
            + ":" + (runTime % 60).ToString("00");
    }
}
```

I am using VS 2017.

Comment: Please don't describe your problem in text without also providing a [mcve]. There are multiple timers available in the framework, so exact code is extremely useful.

Comment: I'm following this question and I'm happy to vote to reopen if you can provide the [mcve].

Comment: What is the value of the `Interval` of the `timer` and the `timer2`?

Comment: I really think you have a misunderstanding as to what `.Refresh()` and `.Thread.Yield()` do.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, 1000 for both.

Comment: @Enigmativity, that could very well be, but more likely for Thread.Yield().

Comment: Don't use exception handling for situations where you can easily code around it (i.e. `lvTimer.Items[...]` & `catch (IndexOutOfRangeException ei)`.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `.Play()` and `.PlaySync()`?

Comment: What is the type of the `snd` object? Could you also include the code of the `fMain2.Designer.cs` file?

Comment: You are 13 variables, at least, away from having a [mcve]. It makes a big difference to refactoring.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - `snd` is `System.Media.SoundPlayer`.

Comment: @taxidev If you find the answer, please mark it as the answer. This would help the person who has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Windows.Forms.Timer` is designed to run code on the UI thread. Calling `System.Threading.Thread.Yield()` tells the system to run another thread that is ready to run on the current core, but your timers want to run on the UI thread so it doesn't help in any way.

It seems to me that you're blocking the UI thread playing your sound with `.PlaySync()`.

I'm going to suggest that you push the playing of the sound to a background thread to free up the UI.

From what I can gather from your code, you're trying to play a series of sounds like this:

```
"Begin.wav", then "ListItem1.wav", then"Go.wav"
(wait a period of time)
"ListItem2.wav", then "Go.wav"
(wait a period of time)
"ListItem3.wav", then "Go.wav"
(wait a period of time)
"End.wav"
```

However, if a timer runs out then cancel playing these sounds and play a `"Stop.wav"` sound instead.

This structure can be modelled with a `Queue<Queue<string>>` and you just need to a nested dequeue and pay all of the sounds.

```
Queue<Queue<string>> queue =
    new Queue<Queue<string>>(new[]
    {
        new Queue<string>(new[] { "Begin.wav", "ListItem1.wav", "Go.wav" }),
        new Queue<string>(new[] { "ListItem2.wav", "Go.wav" }),
        new Queue<string>(new[] { "ListItem3.wav", "Go.wav" }),
        new Queue<string>(new[] { "End.wav" }),
    });
```

Here's the code to dequeue the queues:

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken ct = cts.Token;

Task task = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while (queue.Any())
    {
        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            break;
        }
        Queue<string> inner = queue.Dequeue();
        while (inner.Any())
        {
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                break;
            }
            string soundLocation = inner.Dequeue();
            using (System.Media.SoundPlayer sp = new System.Media.SoundPlayer())
            {
                sp.SoundLocation = soundLocation;
                sp.PlaySync();
            }
        }
        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            using (System.Media.SoundPlayer sp = new System.Media.SoundPlayer())
            {
                sp.SoundLocation = soundLocationStop;
                sp.PlaySync();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0));
        }
    }
});
```

Note that this is all run in a `Task.Run` so it's not blocking the UI thread.

To stop the processing of the sound, just call `cts.Cancel();`.

You now just need to build your queue in the `cmdRun_Click` method.

```
private void cmdRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[][] soundLocationGroups =
    (
        from x in lvTimer.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
        from y in x.SubItems.Cast<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>()
        select new[] { Path.Combine(strSoundFilePath, $"{y.Text}.wav"), Path.Combine(strSoundFilePath, $"Go.wav") }
    ).ToArray();
        
    soundLocationGroups =
        soundLocationGroups
            .Take(1)
            .Select(xs => xs.Prepend(Path.Combine(strSoundFilePath, $"Begin.wav")).ToArray())
            .Concat(soundLocationGroups.Skip(1))
            .Append(new[] { Path.Combine(strSoundFilePath, $"End.wav") })
            .ToArray();
            
    string soundLocationStop = Path.Combine(strSoundFilePath, $"Stop.wav");             

    Queue<Queue<string>> queue = new Queue<Queue<string>>(soundLocationGroups.Select(x => new Queue<string>(x)));
```

You still need a single timer to know if you should call `cts.Cancel()`.

I did test my `Task.Run` code before posting. It works.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

**Step 1:** Get rid of all the `System.Threading.Thread.Yield();` calls.
**Step 2:** Get rid of all the `.Refresh();` calls.
**Step 3:** Make the `timerTick` `async`: `private async void timerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)`
**Step 4:** Replace every occurrence of `snd.PlaySync();` with `await Task.Run(() => snd.PlaySync());`

The [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) method invokes the specified lambda on the [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool). The [`await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await) allows the current thread to continue doing other things, like responding to user input, while the lambda is running on the `ThreadPool`. After the lambda completes, the current thread continues executing the code that follows the `await`, until the next `await`, or until the end of the handler.

After doing these changes the UI should be responsive again, and the other timer should be ticking normally every second.

Be aware that by making the `timerTick` handler `async`, it is now possible to be invoked in an overlapping manner. It's up to you to prevent the overlapping, by checking and updating fields of the form.

Comment: Don't forget to dispose the `SoundPlayer` too.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, from what I can understand of your description, Timer2 is the one that needs to run outside of the main thread.  My experience with threading is nil.

Timer tick event is the main thread, and it runs and then updates labels and increments down the listview.  Timer2 just runs and updates the one label with the updated time and should be able to do that regardless of what Timer is doing.

Am I seeing that straight?

So, how can I get Timer2 to just keep running while Timer does its thing?

Comment: @taxidev both timers should run on the UI thread, because they interact with UI components. UI components should be touched exclusively by the UI thread, because they are thread-affine. My suggestion is to offload to the `ThreadPool` only the `snd.PlaySync()` line, and leave everything else to the UI thread. My answer shows how to do it.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I tried what you showed, but the soundplayer just goes on playing all the sounds without waiting for the rest of the code to run.  So, that's a no-go.  I appreciate your attempt at helping me.

Comment: I understand the conflict with UI objects between 2 threads, but is it possible in threading for one thread to increment a global variable and the originating thread to read that variable?

Comment: @taxidev the sounds should be played sequentially, the one after the other. Are you sure that you included the `await` before the `Task.Run`?

Comment: @taxidev managing shared state in a multithreading environment is tricky. You should know what you are doing. Otherwise, if you go by the instinct, there are numerous non-obvious traps to fall in.